# How to extract all files from a tar.gz with same names, but different content without overwriting repeated files

Tags: unix, tar, data-transfer, duplicate

My tar.gz has **multiple files with the same name but each file having different content** ex: a.csv, b.csv, c.csv, a.csv, d.csv, a.csv and c.csv.
If I do

```
tar -xvf filename.tar.gz | wc -l
```

I'll get the count as 7 files, but when I extract the tar files and do

```
ls | wc -l
```

latest files a.csv and c.csv are overwriting the older a.csv and c.csv, as a result, the word count will be 4 as a result, I'm losing data stored in the other 3 files (a.csv, a.csv, c.csv)

**Is there any way to extract all the files(ex: all 7 files) including the ones with the same name so that there won't be any loss of data for me?**

When I tried searching **tar manual,** there are certain options like **occurrence, --keep-old-files, --keep-newer-files, -k,** but nothing is working out.

Do you have any suggestions for me or did any one of you dealt with this kind of situation earlier?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the `--backup=numbered` option to turn filename collisions into numbered backups.

Comment: The files were present in tar.gz, can I use --backup=numbered while extracting tar.gz?